# javascript concat

Tags: javascript

I have a several arrays that I need to concat into a new one. I'm doing this:

```
function ConcatArrays() {

     var TheNewArray = [];

     function TheConcat(TheArray) { TheNewArray = TheNewArray.concat(TheArray); }

     for (var i = 0; i < SomeArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {

         if (SomeCondition) { TheConcat(SomeArrayOfObjects[i]); }
     }
}
```

For some reason, `TheNewArray` is always empty. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Concat expects an array parameter, you don't need to loop over the array. If you want to add single items based on `SomeCondition`, use `push`.

Comment: Where are you checking the value of `TheNewArray`? It's not accessible outside of `ConcatArrays`.

Comment: @aspillers: there's more code after the loop that deals with TheNewArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a new array to the local parameter.
This does not affect that variable that you passed as a parameter.

You can add an array to an existing array instance (as opposed to creating a new array) like this:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(oldArray, newArray);
```

Comment: Can I fix my code without having to touch the prototype of arrays?'

Comment: This does not touch the prototype. It merely calls a method every array has on a different array. It is equal to `oldArray.push(newArray[0], newArray[1], ..., newArray[newArray.length-1])`

Comment: @frenchie - do you understand that you don't even need a custom function for what you are doing.  You can just use the `.concat()` method of the array?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly concat arrays using the `.concat()` method of an existing array.  I don't understand exactly what method you're trying to write, but if you have three arrays, you can combine them like this:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
var c = [7,8,9];

var d = a.concat(b,c);   // creates [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/N4ews/

The `array.concat()` method will take either individual elements to add to the array or arrays.  If you pass arrays, it will loop through the arrays and get all the elements for you.  See the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for more info on `.concat()` for arrays.